# Using Linq to iterate groups and change property with condition

Tags: c#, linq

I want to iterate through each group and set `"IsQualified= true"` for only first student whose `"University= OPQ"`. (Example: `Emity` in Group 2, J`acob` in Group 3, `White` in Group 5)

**What I tried**

```
        var results= StudentsList
            .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
            .Where(x => x.Any(y => y.University == "OPQ"))
            .FirstOrDefault
            .ToList();

      results.ForEach(x => x.IsQualified = true);

      foreach(var item in results){if (item.IsQualified== true){
      Console.WriteLine("Group " + item.GroupID + " , " + item.Student);}}
```

This does completely the opposite. I change `"IsQualified=True"` for all items in the 1st group! That's not what I want.

**My Code:**

```
List<StudentInfo> StudentsList = new List<StudentInfo>();

// Group 1
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Gungun", University="cdf", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=false});
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="John", University="abc", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=false});
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Jack", University="def", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Peter", University="abc", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Lemity", University="abc", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=false} );

// Group 2
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Donald", University="def", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Olivia", University="ggh", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Emity", University="OPQ", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Emma", University="OPQ", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Alan", University="OPQ", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=false} );

// Group 3
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Adam", University="yub", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Jacob", University="OPQ", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Matthew", University="OPQ", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Saint", University="abc", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Joshua", University="qer", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Aubrey", University="fef", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=false} );

// Group 4
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Caleb", University="DEF", GroupID = 4, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Anna", University="ABC", GroupID = 4, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Chill", University="GHI", GroupID = 4, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Alexis", University="JKL", GroupID = 4, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Zoe", University="MNO", GroupID = 4, IsQualified=false} );

// Group 5
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Dylan", University="PQR", GroupID = 5, IsQualified=false} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="White", University="OPQ", GroupID = 5, IsQualified=false} );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l3p469)

1. You should adjust `Where` clause to filter before grouping.
2. You can get the first item for each group by using `First()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`. Simply because the `Where` clause has already filtered to make sure that each group will have at least one item.
3. In terms of **Performance**, According to @Çöđěxěŕ's comment, Instead of iterating through the LINQ results (to update), You just update records on the fly as part of the query. It means no need for this code `results.ForEach(x => x.IsQualified = true);` anymore.

```
    var results = StudentsList
            .Where(x => x.University == "OPQ")
            .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
            .Select(g => 
                    {
                        var firstItem = g.First();
                        firstItem.IsQualified = true;

                        return firstItem;
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Instead of iterating through the `linq` results (to update), why not just update records on the fly as part of the query? Of course it's not the issue, just a suggestion :), great answer.

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer, please take  a look at

Comment: You did help me in the morning too. Thanks :)

Comment: @Phong that's more like it :) The answer is great along with an improvement besides the issue; I like seeing answers like this.

Comment: @Phong Sorry to interrupt you. Is it possible to add one more condition?

Instead of:
".... for only first student whose University= OPQ"...

Can we make it-
".... for only first student whose University= OPQ and same group don't contain any student with the name Adam."

So the output shall only be Emity and White (since Jacob's group already contains Adam)

I tried this way but it didn't work:
".Where(x => x.University == "OPQ" && x.Student!="Adam")"

I also tried using .Where and .Any inside the "Select" clauses with no luck.

Comment: To keep the simple question (For the reader in the future), you can create a new question and tag me. I'll help you.

Comment: @Phong Hi, will you be able to answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359312/store-linq-function-into-variable-define-on-the-fly?noredirect=1#comment106773551_60359312

Answer (score 3):

```
var firstPerGroup = StudentsList
                .Where(s => s.University == "OPQ")
                .GroupBy(s => s.GroupID)
                .Select(g => g.First())
                .ToList();
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should add more explanation to help the OP know the reason why.

Comment: `g.First()` is enough since we can't have empty groups here;

Comment: By *swapping* `Where` and `GroupBy` we can *guarantee* at least 1 student in each `group`, it's a crucial moment in this solution. On the other hand `GroupBy` followed `Where` (in the original code in the question) can eliminate all the items within a group, so `FirstOrDefault` returns `null`  and we are in trouble

Comment: Sure, @Phong answer is more complete, I just posted the main thought. I can update it, but must confirm that Phong was few seconds faster than me, therefore I gave him my UP vote :)

Comment: Thank you so much @TomasChabada and #Phong both of you. I wish I could accept both of your answers as best :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var results = StudentsList.Where(x => x.University == "OPQ").GroupBy(x => x.GroupID).ToList();
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Group " + item.Key + " , " + item.FirstOrDefault().Student); 
            }
```

You should first filter students by university, and then group by groupID. You will get a structure in which the key is the group number, and the value is a list of `StudentInfo` objects. From this list you need to choose the first student.