# Store Linq function into Variable & define on the fly?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, delegates

I have a Linq query like this

```
var results= StudentsList.GroupBy(x=> x.GroupID)
    .GroupBy(x=> x.Any(g=>g.IsQualified== true))
    .Select(g=> g)
    .ToList();
```

I want to store the part `x.Any(g=>g.IsQualified== true)` into a variable so that I can change it on the fly (example: `x.Any(g=>g.StudentName== "John")` ) based on my requirement and without defining a new Linq query separately. Is that possible?

**Pseudo Code**

```
static void SomeFunction(Func<int, int> op)
  {
        var results= StudentsList.GroupBy(x=> x.GroupID)
            .GroupBy(x=> op))
            .Select(g=> g)
            .ToList();
  }
```

And call it:

```
SomeFunction(x => x.Any(g=>g.IsQualified== true));
SomeFunction(x => x.Any(g=>g.StudentName== "John"));
SomeFunction(x => x.Any(g=>g.Country== "USA"));
```

Comment: You'd want a `Func<IGrouping<int, Student>, bool>` where I'm assuming that `GroupID` is `int` and the `StudentList` is a collection of `Student` objects and that you always want the second grouping to be on a `bool` value.  And uses it like `GroupBy(op)`.  Thought if it's always going to be `x => x.Any(...)` you might want to pass in the predicate for `Any` instead.

Comment: Look at the method signature of the GroupBy function, just make your SomeFunction take in the exact time. It will be either `Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>>` if you are working with a IQueryable or `Func<TSource,TKey>` if you are working with a IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l3p469)

**Solution 1**

You can use `Func<StudentInfo, bool>` to achieve it.

```
private static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, StudentInfo>>  SomeFunction(List<StudentInfo> list, Func<StudentInfo, bool> selector)
{
    return list.GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
                              .Where(g => g.Any(selector) )
                              .Select(g => g);
}
```

*How to use it?*

```
var result1 = SomeFunction(StudentsList, p => p.IsQualified == true);
var result2 = SomeFunction(StudentsList, p => p.Student == "Adam");
```

**Solution 2 *(Create Extension method)***

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, StudentInfo>> ExtensionMethod_SomeFunction(this IEnumerable<StudentInfo> list, Func<StudentInfo, bool> selector) 
{
    return list.GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
                              .Where(g => g.Any(selector) )
                              .Select(g => g);
}
```

*How to use it?*

```
var result3 = StudentsList.ExtensionMethod_SomeFunction(p => p.IsQualified == true);
var result4 = StudentsList.ExtensionMethod_SomeFunction(p => p.Student == "John");
```

Comment: You're my Guru!

Comment: I get this error `... not all code paths return a value` when I 1) Make the IEnumerable non-static and 2) Use `.ToList();` at the end to update the collection, instead of returning items with `return list.GroupBy....`

Comment: @YoKidYo  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208379/yokidyo

Comment: Hi @Phong, would you like to contribute here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60635036/issue-with-custom-styled-progress-bar