# Issue with Custom Styled Progress Bar

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'm trying to accomplish a custom styled Progress Bar for my C# WPF application that looks like this-

[image: sample]

**User Control Code:**

```
 <UserControl x:Class="CustomControl"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      Height="120" Width="120" Background="Transparent">
      <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
          <Grid.RenderTransform>
             <ScaleTransform x:Name="SpinnerScale"
                              ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0" />
          </Grid.RenderTransform>
          <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Width="120" Height="120" >
              <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862"
                       Canvas.Left="20.1696"
                       Canvas.Top="9.76358"
                       Stretch="Fill" Fill="Orange"
                       Opacity="1.0"/>
              <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862"
                       Canvas.Left="2.86816"
                       Canvas.Top="29.9581" Stretch="Fill"
                       Fill="Black" Opacity="0.9"/>
              <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862"
                       Canvas.Left="5.03758e-006"
                       Canvas.Top="57.9341" Stretch="Fill"
                       Fill="Black" Opacity="0.8"/>
              <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862"
                       Canvas.Left="12.1203"
                       Canvas.Top="83.3163" Stretch="Fill"
                       Fill="Black" Opacity="0.7"/>
              <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862"
                       Canvas.Left="36.5459"
                       Canvas.Top="98.138" Stretch="Fill"
                       Fill="Black" Opacity="0.6"/>
              <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862"
                       Canvas.Left="64.6723"
                       Canvas.Top="96.8411" Stretch="Fill"
                       Fill="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
              <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862"
                       Canvas.Left="87.6176"
                       Canvas.Top="81.2783" Stretch="Fill"
                       Fill="Black" Opacity="0.4"/>
              <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862"
                       Canvas.Left="98.165"
                       Canvas.Top="54.414" Stretch="Fill"
                       Fill="Black" Opacity="0.3"/>
           <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862"
                      Canvas.Left="92.9838"
                  Canvas.Top="26.9938" Stretch="Fill"
                      Fill="Black" Opacity="0.2"/>
            <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862"
                      Canvas.Left="47.2783"
                     Canvas.Top="0.5" Stretch="Fill"
                       Fill="Black" Opacity="0.1"/>
              <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                  <RotateTransform x:Name="SpinnerRotate"
                                   Angle="0" />
             </Canvas.RenderTransform>
              <Canvas.Triggers>
                  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContentControl.Loaded">
                      <BeginStoryboard>
                          <Storyboard>
                              <DoubleAnimation
                                  Storyboard.TargetName
                                      ="SpinnerRotate"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty
                                      ="(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                   From="0" To="360"
                                   Duration="0:0:01"
                                   RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                          </Storyboard>
                      </BeginStoryboard>
                  </EventTrigger>
              </Canvas.Triggers>
          </Canvas>
      </Grid>
  </UserControl>
```

**Codebehind**

The code behind the user control is as follows:

```
   public partial class CustomControl : UserControl
      {
          public CustomControl()
          {
              InitializeComponent();

              Timeline.DesiredFrameRateProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                  typeof(Timeline),
                      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { DefaultValue = 20 } );
          }
      }
```

**The Problem**

The output is much different than my expectation. I struggled many hours with no success. Please help me to get expected results.

[image]

Comment: follow [link](https://youtu.be/o7MGaf8YW6s)

Comment: follow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4871370/11362349)